# how to write command in command prompt (cmd) in windows 10 from python script with subprocess module

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, command-prompt

I need to launch external program from python script, which can be run in command prompt. I've been searching through python documentations and stack overflow but can't find anything helpful to me. I successfully launch cmd with following script:
[image]

[image]

But I still need to write down more commands like that:

- mkdir data
- copy data.txt c:\data

[image]

I think this is a very easy job with subprocess module but I can't find the way. How can I do this?

Comment: isn't this just `subprocess.run("mkdir data && copy data.txt C:\data", shell=True)`?

Comment: @AdamSmith, It seems not to make a data folder at c:\ with 'subprocess.run("mkdir data && copy data.txt C:\data", shell=True)'. Is it something wrong to me?

Comment: Making this work is not a problem, but why use CMD to make a directory and copy a file? It's simple to use Python `os.mkdir('data');` `shutil.copy('data.txt', 'data')`.

Comment: @eryksun, you are right. Making directory via 'os.mkdir' or 'shutil.copy' is a easy way but I have several similar jobs like that. So if I can do these jobs, I also can do other jobs as well. Therefore, I need to know how 'subprocess' works to operate command-prompt.

Comment: `shell=True` uses `'cmd.exe /c "{}"'.format(args)`. This executes a single command line, which can include multiple commands joined by `&&`, `||`, `&`, and `|` (pipe). CMD waits for the command-line to finish and exits with the evaluated exit code. You can use `start` to avoid waiting on a command or `start /b` to do so without creating a new console, and redirect stdin and stdout (e.g. to NUL) if necessary using `<` and `>`. Make sure string literals used for the command line are either raw or escape backslashes.

Comment: @Sang-ilAhn your original code didn't make `C:\data`, it made `%CD%\data`. I did the same... was that incorrect?

Answer (score -2):

Try to use call

`subprocess.call(['cmd.exe', 'mkdir data']);`

Comment: sorry i just tried different process in linux, but in this case, you can use os, os.system('mkdir data');